# Auto deduct when barcode is scanned - Javascript, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to create a simple form, just like at the supermarket system, when checkout at the counter, they just scan the barcode on the item, and the quantity of the item is added automatically.

The problem is, i dont know which event(onkeyup,onkeypress, etc..) to use on the textfield.

This is my simple code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#acc_no").on('input', function() {

var a = document.getElementById("acc_no").value;
var b = document.getElementById("qty_dead").value;

if(b == '')
{
    qty = 0;
}
else
{
var qty = parseInt(b);
qty +=1
}
document.getElementById("qty_dead").value = qty;
document.form1.acc_no.select();

})
});
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="document.form1.acc_no.select()">
<form action="deduct_stage_two_submit.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
Accession No:<br />
<input name="acc_no" type="text" id="acc_no" onkeypress="calc()" autocomplete="off"/><br />
Dead Quantity:<br />
<input name="qty_dead" type="text" id="qty_dead" onkeypress="calc()" />
<br />
Date:<br />
<input name="date_dead" type="text" id="date_dead"/><br />
Batch Date Out Stage 1:<br />
<input name="date_out" type="text" id="date_out"/><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would try the .change(). According to jQuery API Docs 'It is also displayed if you change the text in the field and then click away.'

Comment: @Rcls, can you give an example using .change()? a simple one is suffice.

Comment: $('input[name="acc_no"]').change(function() {
        alert('You have changed the input'); // Put your stuff here
 }); // The only bad thing here is that you have to lose focus or submit form to actually get something. It doesn't trigger on just inserting a barcode generated string of characters.

Comment: i googled the .change() jquery and come out with simple solution. but still need to lose focus for the .change() to work. Is there any solution on this?

Comment: You can try jQuery's focusout() event to lose focus after the barcode has been set in the input field and there hasnt been any activity for 1 second. Create a timer to start when the last keystroke was pressed and 1 second later lose focus. I would suggest trying to search some type of event similar to keyup() since keyup reacts to every keystroke and I think a barcode generating into an input field reads as multiple keystrokes and then your code executes itself on every keystroke, unless you set it to read the string length.

Comment: I assume you're using some kind of barcode scanning hardware, they're usually configured to press tab or enter once it's filled in a barcode. Find out which key it simulates pressing, then listen to keyup watching for that key.